# EBImage feature names

Tags: r, image-processing, bioconductor

Can anyone explain what is being used to compute different features within `computeFeatures`?

I get the naming convention being applied that is spelled out in `? computeFeatures`. I don't understand the `.0.`, `.a.` and `.Ba.` labels.

For example:

```
> library(EBImage)
> y = readImage(system.file("images", "nuclei.tif", package="EBImage"))[,,1]
> x = thresh(y, 10, 10, 0.05)
> x = opening(x, makeBrush(5, shape='disc'))
> x = bwlabel(x)
> ft = computeFeatures(x, y, xname="nucleus")
> colnames(ft)
 [1] "nucleus.0.m.cx"            "nucleus.0.m.cy"           
 [3] "nucleus.0.m.majoraxis"     "nucleus.0.m.eccentricity" 
<snip>
[11] "nucleus.0.s.radius.max"    "nucleus.a.b.mean"         
[13] "nucleus.a.b.sd"            "nucleus.a.b.mad"          
<snip>
[51] "nucleus.Ba.b.mean"         "nucleus.Ba.b.sd"          
[53] "nucleus.Ba.b.mad"          "nucleus.Ba.b.q001"        
[55] "nucleus.Ba.b.q005"         "nucleus.Ba.b.q05"  
<snip>
```

My guess is `nucleus.0.*` features use only the data from the binary masks contained in `x`. So `nucleus.0.m.cy` is the y-axis centroid computed using the binary data. There are also `nucleus.a.m.cy` and `nucleus.Ba.m.cy` but it is unclear how these computations are different (they are extremely correlated but not identical).

I also suppose the `.a.` and `.Ba.` use the intensity values in `y` but the details are vague. Features like `nucleus.a.b.mean` and `nucleus.Ba.b.mean` are similar (~.80 corr) but not the same. I assume that they estimate the mean `y` intensity of objects defined by the labels in `x` but the difference is unclear.

Is there any documentation on this?

Thanks,

Max

```
> sessionInfo()
R Under development (unstable) (2014-08-23 r66461)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] EBImage_4.7.16

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] abind_1.4-0         BiocGenerics_0.11.4 grid_3.2.0         
 [4] jpeg_0.1-8          lattice_0.20-29     locfit_1.5-9.1     
 [7] parallel_3.2.0      png_0.1-7           tiff_0.1-5         
[10] tools_3.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the documentation here: [AnalysisWithEBImage](http://bioconductor.wustl.edu/bioc/vignettes/EBImage/inst/doc/AnalysisWithEBImage.pdf)

This seems to be the most in depth document that discusses the package. Have you tried contacting the author Grégoire Pau directly? Im sure if you google him you can find him.

Comment: I have but 1) a lot of that specific syntax is deprecated and 2) it does;t mention `computeFeatures`. I wanted to ask the question here before bothering the package maintainer (as I would like someone to do for my packages). Thanks, Max

Answer (score 1):

As a disclaimer, I know nothing of your field, but by looking at the function I can make a pretty good guess at what is going on. I recommend that you use `debugonce(computeFeatures)` and then run `ft = computeFeatures(x, y, xname="nucleus")`. You can step through each line of the code (type `Q`) to exit, and see what is going on.

As you noted, the documentation states:

> Features are named x.y.f, where x is the object layer, y the
>        reference image layer and f the feature name.

In your example `computeFeatures` has generated values for *three* reference layers (`a`, `aB`, and `0`). The documentation mentions that if you don't name your reference layers, they will just be given the letters of the alphabet, so in your case you had one reference layer, and it is called `a`. I believe the `0` means that it uses *no* reference layer.

From looking at the source code, it appears that for every layer *i*, a B_*i* layer is created. It appears to pass a hardcoded filter over each layer as you can see in this code, found in the `expandRef` function (the comments are mine):

```
# Hard code a filter
blob = gblob(x0 = 15, n = 49, alpha = 0.8, beta = 1.2)
# Filter using the fast 2D FFT convolution product.
bref = lapply(ref, function(r) filter2(r, blob)/2)
# Name it "B" and then the layer name
names(bref) = paste("B", names(ref), sep = "")
```

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do here, but you can see visually what this filter is doing. Here is your `x` (you can just run `display(x)` to see it):

[image]

Here is your reference (`y`):

[image]

Here is what the hardcoded filter looks like:

[image]

And this is what the hardcoded filter does to `y`:

[image]

So, to summarize: everything with `0` is comparing to a no reference, everything with `a` is comparing directly to `y` as a reference, and everything with `aB` is comparing to a filtered version of `y`.

Comment: After reading a bit more about this, I suspect that what the hardcoded filter is doing is applying a 15 pixel [Gaussian blur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur), which would be useful if you needed to do edge detection.

Comment: I know what the code is try to do, but I'm looking for more detail regarding the exact details of what data are use to compute the features relative to the naming convention. There is only 1 reference object here (`y`); more than one reference object would require a list of matrices (and, for the given example, using more than one value in `reframes` throws an error). If I use something like `refnames = "prot"`, the convention becomes "`.prot.`" and "`.Bprot.`" instead of "`.a.`" and "`.Ba`" which is a little more defined but doesn't explain the computations.

Comment: Although you only input one reference object (`y`), it creates *two* reference objects for each reference object you enter, one as you entered, and the other with a Gaussian blur. As I mentioned, it always prefixes "B" to the Gaussian blur. The exact blur it uses is also given in the code above. Finally, it adds a third reference, called `0`, which uses no reference.